# mqtt.js after unscbribe still receive messages from old listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, mqtt

I'm using mqtt.js to receive websocket from mqtt server , the subscription works fine , but i need to change the subscription to topic dynamically through changing the configuration of the websocket , the issue is that after changing the configurations the i start to receive messages from both the new topic and the old topic , the old listener remains active even after i do client.unsubscribe().

is there a way to delete the old lister or stop the old websocket and keep only the new websocket, below is a snippet from the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import mqtt from 'mqtt';

 var options = {
              protocol: 'ws',
              rejectUnauthorized: false,
              clientId: 'clientid' ,
              username: 'username',
              password: 'password',
              clean: true
          };
 if (subscribed && (subscription != subscription1) && (subscription !=''))
                {

                    console.log("subscription != subscription1 and changing configurations");

                    console.log("previous subscription is : " , subscription)

                    console.log("New subscription is : ", subscription1)

                    client.unsubscribe(subscription, () => 
                                               
                        
                         {

                               client.end(true, () => {
                                console.log("client ended")

                                // console.log("connection status is : ", connectionStatus, "subscription is : ", subscription1);

                                console.log("subscribing to :", subscription1.toString());

                                client = mqtt.connect('ws://server:port/mqtt', options);


                                Configchanged = true;

                                client.subscribe(subscription1.toString(), (err, granted) => {

                                    if (granted) {

                                        var note = '';
                                        if (client) {

                                            client.on('message', function dispatchMqttTempMsg(topic, message) {

                                                note = message.toString();

                                                setValue(parseFloat(note));
                                                console.log("received value to listener is", note)
                                            })


                                        }

                                    }


                                    else {

                                        console.log("error during subscription", err)
                                    }

                                });



                            })                  
                    
                    
                    
                    })
                    // client.close(true)

                    
                    // console.log("unsubscribing for guage no. ", props.id, "topic : ", subscription )
                  
                            


                        }

                   
                    subscription = subscription1;

                }
                  
            }
```

the  client.on('message',..) above keeps active even if unsubscribed successfully..

Comment: I think you are trying to be too tricky in your code ;)  You are trying to client.subscribe() within your client.end() function....that seems like a conflict to me and you might be throwing errors that you are not catching.  Try separating the client.subscribe() from your client.unsubscribe() block, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the unsubscribe is not working correctly , I have to make another procedure to unsubscribe from all previous topics before i subscribe to the new topic , this way the websocket listener will be removed and i wont receive messages from the old topic.